# format @book and @inbook entries in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I've just turned to `biblatex` from `bibtex`. I am newbie to the `biblatex`. I am trying to figure out how to use the `biblatex` to meet my uni's bibliography requirements. My LaTex code is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, british]{article}
\usepackage{babel} % Switch to English style quotation mark, remember to add british to document option
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Vanschoenwinkel2016,
  author  = {Vanschoenwinkel, Janka and Mendelsohn, Robert and Van Passel,
             Steven},
  title   = {Do Western and Eastern Europe have the same agricultural climate
             response? Taking adaptive capacity into account},
  journal = {Global Environmental Change},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {74-87}
}

@InBook{Adams1999,
  pages     = {1-18},
  title     = {Economic effects of climate change on US agriculture},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  year      = {1999},
  author    = {Adams, Ricahard M. and Mccarl, Bruce A. and Segerson, Kathleen and Rosenzweig, Cynthia and Bryant, Kelly J and Dixon, Bruce L and Conner, Richard and Evenson, Robert E and OJima, Dennis},
  editor    = {Mendelsohn, Robert and Neumann, James E.},
  type      = {Book Section},
  address   = {Cambridge, UK},
  isbn      = {0521607698},
  booktitle = {The Impact of Climate Change on the United States Economy},
}

@Book{Cline2007,
  title     = {Global Warming and Agriculture:Impacts Estimates by Contry},
  publisher = {Edward},
  year      = {2007},
  author    = {Cline, William R.},
  address   = {Washington DC},
  type      = {Book},
}

@TechReport{Dasgupta2007,
  author      = {Dasgupta, Susmita and Laplante, Benoit and Meisner, Craig and Wheeler, David and Yan, Jianping},
  title       = {The Impact of Sea Level Rise on Developing Countries: A Comparative Analysis},
  institution = {World Bank},
  year        = {2007},
  type        = {Report},
  number      = {World Bank Policy Research Working paper 4136},
  address     = {Washington DC},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, giveninits=true,backend=biber, maxcitenames=3,%
            maxbibnames=9, sortcites, url=false, backref=false,]{biblatex}


\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace} % Replace dot with comma in reference after Author + Year

%\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} %add comma between author and year in the intext-citation
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} % Suppress In: in the reference list

%use ":" after year in the intext citation
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

%format page range of @article and @incollection follow this format: volume(number): page range.
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon\addspace}{\addcomma\addspace}}


\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}

%format volume and number as follow: volume(number)

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addnbspace}% NEW (optional); there's also \addnbthinspace
  \printfield{number}%
  \printunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% replace dot “.” by comma “,” after title in biblatex for @article
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \printunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {}
  {}

  \addbibresource{test.bib}

  \begin{document}
  This is cited by @ariticle entry: \parencite{Vanschoenwinkel2016}. 
  This is cited by @inbook entry: (\cite{Adams1999}).
  This is cited by @book entry \cite{Cline2007}. 
  This is cited by @technicalreport: \parencite{Dasgupta2007}

  \printbibliography

  \end{document}
```

and the output is

[image]

Now, I want reformat for `@inbook` and `@book` with the format as following:

[image]

Any suggestion for me with above format?

Secondly, I would like to put the title of `@Techreport` between single quotes ' '

Comment: Don't use the `inbook` entry type for papers included in an edited volume. Use the `incollection` entry type. `inbook` is typically for use to reference a single chapter of a book by one author or set of authors.  For your edited book, you need to change `author` to `editor` in the `.bib` entry. (How else can `biblatex` know that the name is an editor? :) )

Comment: Are your other typographic conventions British? (Spelling, other punctuation?) If so, just switch to British and `csquates` will sort things out. If not, you need to figure out if you're using a suitable ready-made variant and, if not, what kind of hodge-podge your publisher requires. (They sometimes require pretty bizarre mixtures for reasons I've never understood.)

Comment: @cfr: I did configure in the code with option: 
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper, british]{article}, and use package \usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

Comment: @VũVõ You don't need `autostyle`. If you have `british`, then just loading `csquotes` will get you single quotation marks as primary and Biblatex will use those. Make sure `csquotes` is loaded before `biblatex`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `biblatex-ext` to move the editors around and simplify some of the code you have already.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, giveninits=true, uniquename=init, backend=biber, maxcitenames=3,%
            maxbibnames=9, sortcites, url=false, isbn=false, backref=false,
            articlein=false, innamebeforetitle=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{translatortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{translatortypedelim}{\addspace}

%\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space} %add comma between author and year in the intext-citation

\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
% replace dot “.” by comma “,” after title in biblatex for @article
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \printunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {}
  {}

% remove chapter and pages
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}
  {}{}

% add them into the new position
\xpatchbibmacro{incollection:parent}
  {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock}
  {\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}}
  {}{}


\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext[emph]{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}

%format volume and number as follow: volume(number)
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addnbspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

%format page range of @article and @incollection follow this format: volume(number): page range.
\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addcomma}\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}

%use ":" after year in the intext citation
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Vanschoenwinkel2016,
  author  = {Vanschoenwinkel, Janka and Mendelsohn, Robert and Van Passel,
             Steven},
  title   = {Do Western and Eastern Europe have the same agricultural climate
             response? Taking adaptive capacity into account},
  journal = {Global Environmental Change},
  year    = {2016},
  volume  = {41},
  number  = {7},
  pages   = {74-87}
}

@incollection{Adams1999,
  pages     = {1-18},
  title     = {Economic effects of climate change on US agriculture},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  year      = {1999},
  author    = {Adams, Ricahard M. and Mccarl, Bruce A. and Segerson, Kathleen and Rosenzweig, Cynthia and Bryant, Kelly J and Dixon, Bruce L and Conner, Richard and Evenson, Robert E and OJima, Dennis},
  editor    = {Mendelsohn, Robert and Neumann, James E.},
  type      = {Book Section},
  address   = {Cambridge, UK},
  isbn      = {0521607698},
  booktitle = {The Impact of Climate Change on the United States Economy},
}

@Book{Cline2007,
  title     = {Global Warming and Agriculture: Impacts Estimates by Contry},
  publisher = {Edward},
  year      = {2007},
  author    = {Cline, William R.},
  address   = {Washington DC},
  type      = {Book},
}

@TechReport{Dasgupta2007,
  author      = {Dasgupta, Susmita and Laplante, Benoit and Meisner, Craig and Wheeler, David and Yan, Jianping},
  title       = {The Impact of Sea Level Rise on Developing Countries: A Comparative Analysis},
  institution = {World Bank},
  year        = {2007},
  type        = {Report},
  number      = {World Bank Policy Research Working paper 4136},
  address     = {Washington DC},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\nocite{westfahl:frontier,westfahl:space}
\begin{document}
  This is cited by @article entry: \parencite{Vanschoenwinkel2016}. 
  This is cited by @inbook entry: \parencite{Adams1999}.
  This is cited by @book entry \cite{Cline2007}. 
  This is cited by @technicalreport: \parencite{Dasgupta2007}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Should get you closer to what you want

[image]

- `biblatex-ext`'s `innamebeforetitle` option does the major work of moving the editors of `@incollection`s.
- `xpatch` is used to move the pages from after the publisher to after the book title.
- `@incollection` instead of `@inbook` (as pointed out by Alan Munn); on the other hand a quick google search suggests that Mr Cline is the *author* of `Cline2007` and so the "(ed.)" would not be appropriate. If he is indeed the editor and the thing turns out to be a collection, you should still the the correct results.
- There were a few issues with punctuation that left me baffled and I could not figure out a way to algorithmically describe what I saw, so you may have to tweak that a bit.

Comment: Are you sure that `babel` affects the quotation marks?

Comment: @cfr Well yes and no. If you refer to the comments in the code after `\usepackage{babel}`, there were copied from the original MWE and I didn't actually read them before, but they are indeed not entirely accurate. But together with `csquotes` (which is loaded much later in the preamble) `babel` does indeed affect the quotation marks (though you could argue that `csquotes` does the real work here). I will remove misleading comments and reorder the preamble to load `hyperref` last.

Comment: It is really `csquotes`, I think. At least, that's how it works for me. I didn't notice that comment was from the OP, but I still think you're right to remove it - thanks for editing. (Can't upvote again.)

Comment: @cfr Yes it is `csquotes` that does the real work here. If you don't load `csquotes` `biblatex` uses an emulation of `csquotes`' commands so that quotation marks produced by `biblatex` always come out as American-style 66-99 quotation marks. If `csquotes` is loaded with `autostyle` it gets the style from the active language.

Comment: @moewe: thanks for your help. the code works well for my case.

Comment: @moewe It gets the style even if you don't use `autostyle`, at least if `british` is a class option.

Comment: @cfr That is because the default is `autostyle=tryonce`, which only tries to adapt the quotation mark once (to the main language). `autostyle=true` continuously adapts the quotation marks to any language changes throughout the document. It makes no difference in the MWE, but again I did not question the intentions of the OP.

Comment: can I back to my problem a little bit? if I use option of "ext-authoryear" of the biblatex (\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear...]{biblatex}), the output is matched with my university. However, if i want to group of the same authors with different years (i.e. (IPCC, 2007; IPCC, 2014) -> (IPCC, 2007, 2014)) by using option of "authoryear-comp", then the output is not generated as I want. How can I adjust the code using with option of "authoryear-comp"?

Comment: @VũVõ `style=ext-authoryear-comp`?

Comment: @moewe: I did try that option, it works well for group of the same author, but not format correctly as requested for \@book and \@incollection

Comment: @VũVõ Sorry, I don't understand. Changing from `style=ext-authoryear` to `style=ext-authoryear-comp` does not change the output of the bibliography at all. It only affects the citations. So if you are OK with the output as shown in the MWE (which was produced with `style=ext-authoryear`), `style=ext-authoryear-comp` should work for you as well.

Comment: @moewe: let me figure out what happens inside. It's probably that there is some conflicts when using many other packages.

Comment: @moewe Ah, yes. I was going by the MWE, where only `american` is used. But the real document may of course use multiple languages with different quotation conventions.