Bibliography, incollection, change order of editor and booktitle
Once again I need help with the citations in LaTeX.
I want to change

Voß, G. G./H. Pongratz (1999): Entgrenzte Arbeitskraft – entgrenzte Qualifikation. In: Bildung und Arbeit, das Ende einer Differenz? Hrsg. von H. Hansen et al. Aarau: Bildung Sauerländer, S. 39–49.

to

Voß, G./Pongratz, H. (1999): Entgrenzte Arbeitskraft – entgrenzte Qualifikation. In: Hansen, H. u. a. (Hrsg.): Bildung und Arbeit – Das Ende einer Differenz? Aarau, S. 39-49.

From:

In: booktitle, Hrsg. von editor: location, S. pages

To:

In: editor, (Hrsg.): booktitle, location, S. Pages

\documentclass[toc=sectionentrywithdots,a4paper,12pt,ngerman,oneside,usegeometry,parskip=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
date=year,
style=authoryear-icomp,
maxnames=2,
minnames=1,
maxbibnames=2,
maxcitenames=2,
giveninits=true,
uniquename=init,
isbn=false,
doi=false,
dashed=false,
sortcites=false
]{biblatex}
% no indent in biblography
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlength\bibitemsep{3pt} %Abstand zwischen zwei Literatureinträgen bib
%Besucht am ins Stand:
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
    urlseen = {Stand:}
}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}% entfernt anführungszeichen im titel
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}% Slash in der Bilbiographie zwischen den Authoren Meyer/Müller
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}% Slash in der Bilbiographie zwischen den Authoren Meyer/Müller

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} %Doppelpunkt nach (2023):; 

% Müller/Meyer not Müller und Maier für textcite und parencite
\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{multinamedelim}{\addspace{}und\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}% Hannover Müller und Meier
\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{multinamedelim}{\slash}% Hannover Müller/Meier
\DeclareDelimAlias[parencite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}% Hannover Müller/Meier
%\DeclareDelimAlias*[parencite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}% Hannover Müller/Meier
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ %anstatt und andere : et al. 
    andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

\AtEveryBibitem{% Clean up the bibtex rather than editing it
    \clearlist{publisher}
}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\textcite{voss1999}
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}

test.bib
@incollection{voss1999,
    title = {Entgrenzte Arbeitskraft -- entgrenzte Qualifikation},
    booktitle = {Bildung und Arbeit, das Ende einer Differenz?},
    author = {Voß, G Günter and Pongratz, Hans},
    editor = {Hansen, Hanja and Voß, G Günter and Pongratz, Hans},
    date = {1999},
    pages = {39--49},
    publisher = {Bildung Sauerländer},
    location = {Aarau},
}


Use a style from the biblatex-ext bundle so that you can use the option innamebeforetitle=true,. Then you only need to redefine the editortype field format and editortypedelim delimiter format.
In a slightly modernised (and simplified) version of your example we then get
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman,parskip=false]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=ext-authoryear-icomp,
  sortcites=false,
  maxnames=2,
  minnames=1,
  maxbibnames=2,
  maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits=true,
  uniquename=init,
  date=year,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  dashed=false,
  innamebeforetitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\setlength\bibitemsep{3pt}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{multinamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,
  patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
  urlseen   = {Stand:},
}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=publisher, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{voss1999,
  title     = {Entgrenzte Arbeitskraft -- entgrenzte Qualifikation},
  booktitle = {Bildung und Arbeit, das Ende einer Differenz?},
  author    = {Voß, G. Günter and Pongratz, Hans},
  editor    = {Hansen, Hanja and Voß, G. Günter and Pongratz, Hans},
  date      = {1999},
  pages     = {39--49},
  publisher = {Bildung Sauerländer},
  location  = {Aarau},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{voss1999,companion,aksin,sigfridsson}

\parencite{voss1999,companion,aksin,sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}



I dropped some of the document class options so that everything would nicely fit into a single line (I don't necessarily recommend you change anything there in your actual document). I do recommend you look at all the biblatex-related changes though. They make the code more idiomatic.

Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173638/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436727/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433562/35864

Thank you very much, everything works as desired, have a nice week.
